# Design pattern for having custom processing in a generic function

Tags: rest, design-patterns

Here is the use case:

I want to develop a rest api to send email so that anyone who want to send email to anybody, can use this api.

Now say one client want to send an email BUT before sending the email, he want to do some book keeping. Say, want to store the sender, receiver information in DB. However, not every client want to store those information.

So, in this case which design pattern will be perfect? I am thinking of using strategy but before that I want to evaluate the options. It would be great help, if anyone provides some input

Comment: this is too high level and you have to be more specific about your question. When you say you want to use strategy, why?

Comment: @Larry let me try. Say one client want to store the recipient's name in db before sending email. One client  want to notify someone before sending email. One client don't want to do anything before sending email, he just need to send the email. I am thinking of having a pre processing interface which will be implemented by different concrete classes and implement the different strategies. Thats why i said stretegy